# How to get Excel to output an interpolated value from a chart

Tags: excel, charts

I'm not sure exactly what this is called, but I have a chart I need to extract information from.  Is there a way to enter some line equations on a chart then get Excel to interpolate between those lines without outputting the equations to tables and using xlookup and interpolation formulas?

The chart below takes in two variables (OAT on the X axis and Pressure Altitude) and the result is read on the Y axis.  Is there a way to get that result?  I'd be willing to learn the Python in Excel feature if there's any additional functionality there...

I'm trying to make this tool so myself as well as some non computer guys can use it.

[Chart in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVzm1.png)

I can build a system of tables and lookups to accomplish this but it takes a while, makes the spreadsheet large with multiple pages and is prone to errors from users.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.